# MySql - Unable to set foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I have a database with tables: Papers and Citations. I have created the papers table as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Papers (
        ID       int NOT NULL,
        TITLE    varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        YEAR     int,
        Publication_Venue  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

And the citations table:

```
CREATE TABLE Citations (
     ID_from     int NOT NULL,
     ID_to       int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_from, ID_to))
```

I have already populated these tables. 
But both of the columns in my citations table should be foreign keys to the ID of the papers table. So I preformed this query to add both of these columns are foreign keys of ID in papers table:

```
ALTER TABLE citations
     ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_from) REFERENCES papers(ID),
      ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_to) REFERENCES papers(ID)
```

But I get the error:

```
'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`literature`.`#sql-500_4c`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-500_4c_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_to`) REFERENCES `papers` (`ID`))')
```

I am very new to sql and cant figure out what the problem is that I cannot set these as foreign keys? Or is it a case that I needed to add these before I populated the tables? Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Most likely you already have values in your table, that would not be allowed under these constraints. One single record in citations with an id that can not be found in papers would be enough to make this fail.

Comment: Your error mentions a table (`literature`) that is not otherwise present in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run your query and there is no problem, the only reason for this error, your table `citations` columns contains data doesn't related to its reference in table `Papers`, so before running this script:

```
ALTER TABLE citations
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_from) REFERENCES papers(ID),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_to) REFERENCES papers(ID)
```

you must be sure there is no data in `ID_from` or `ID_to` doesn't related to `ID` column in `Papers` table